# How in react can i use initialized calss with parametrs

Tags: reactjs, node.js, class, components

Im trying to use instance of the class with parametr in consrutor and after that use render. What am i doing wrong ?

```
Class account:


  import React, { Component } from 'react';
    
    export default class Account extends Component{
    
        #Login
    
        constructor(login){
            super(login);
            this.#Login = login;
            this.state = {
                js: []
            }
            this.#getAccount();
        }
    
        #getAccount = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/search/${this.#Login}`);
                const jsonData = await response.json();
    
                
                const dt = Object.values(jsonData);
                this.setState({js: dt})
    
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        };
    
    
        render(){
            const dataArr = this.state.js;
            return (<form>
                {<table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Account
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Password
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {dataArr.map(el => (
                            <tr>
                                <td>{el.account_name}</td>
                                <td>{el.account_password}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>}
            </form>);
        }
    }
```

search page:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import Account from "./Classes/Account";

const ListOfTopics = () => {
    const acc = new Account(8);

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    return (<form>Search Page
            <h1><acc.render /></h1>
        </form>)
};

export default ListOfTopics;
```

Comment: `new Account(8);` This is just not how react components are designed to be used. You need to use JSX elements, such as `<Account {/* insert props here */}>`, and then react will call the constructor for you. You are not able to do all the set up work that react does. Can you do `login` as a prop instead?